# Send a specific view of web element from workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I would like to know if there is the possibility to send from the workflow a specific view of a form created in infopath and uploaded to SharePoint 2013.

Example:
I have a Vacation Request form with a default view Edit item, and another Area Manager view, I would like that view only to reach the area manager

Hola, me gustaria sable si existe la posibilidad de enviar desde el flujo de trabajo una vista especifica de un formulario creado en infopath y cargado a SharePoint 2013.

Ejemplo:
Tengo un formulario de Solicitud de vacaciones con una vista predeterminada Edit item, y otra vista Jefe de area, me gustaria que esa vista solo le llegara al jefe de area

Answer (score 0):

you could use query string to specify the view name and then use logic in infopath to switch to specif view based on that.

Have a look at this article how to use query string with the IP form. 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form/